Once a google document has been approved, automate PDF creation and move to another folder with Google Apps Script
I'm new Google Apps Script, and I am trying to figure out if the following is possible.
We use Google drives approval system, once a document has been approved, I need the document to convert to PDF, and then that copy of the PDF to be moved to a specific folder (this folder would be read only to most staff).
I can see it is possible to automate the creation of a PDFs and move files. But is it possible to trigger this once a document has been approved, and if so how can this be achieved? Is there a function that can be used to check if documents have been approved? Are there any example scripts that do this?
I'm still learning, and can't see a way to do what I describe.

I cannot understand a document has been approved. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Thanks for replying. Google docs/sheets have an approval mechanism. If you go to File > Approvals, then you can select colleagues to approve the document. Once all the reviewers have clicked "approve", the document becomes locked. We use this to ensure that we have evidence that a document has been formally approved. Details at: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9387535

Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, as a simple approach, from this t, when the value of reason of contentRestrictions is Locked for File Approval, the script can be run by checking the value with the time-driven trigger. If this was not useful, I apologize.
